# Reloading contact into session fails

Tags: xdb, session-state, contact

The solution is based on Sitecore 9.0.2 and two machines: CM and CD.

I'm doing some changes to the contact profile and I want to reload it to the session as described here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/contactmanager-reference.html

```
manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Contact = manager.LoadContact(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
```

The code works fine on CD, but on CM `manager.LoadContact()` returns null.

What is the reason and how to fix that?

Comment: Are there any errors in the log when this happens?

Comment: No errors in the log.

Answer (score 1):

The CM server does not process xDB since the role `ContentDelivery` or `Standalone` is not enabled. This is by default to prevent CM activity from polluting the xDB database. Your code will only work on the CD servers or servers with `Standalone` role enabled.

Comment: Is there any documentation to describe that? I didn't find any when converting from Standalone to CM/CD, so I didn't modify the code to include that. According to articles like https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/02/12/sitecore-analytics-tracker-common-issues-and-how-to-resolve-them/ the tracker can be used on CM if the Analytics.ClusterName is pointing to CD.